# How to use the m2m_changed signal to update models information in django 4.2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models team and project and both models have fields that have a many to many relatioships with each other. I want to be able automatically update the second model say teams when i update the teams field in the projects model.

project model

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .team import Team
class Project(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'Pending'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'In Progress'
    COMPLETED = 'Completed'

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (IN_PROGRESS, 'In Progress'),
        (COMPLETED, 'Completed'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', blank=True, related_name='team_projects')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

teams model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# from . import Project

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project', blank=True, related_name='teams_projects')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

I have tried to research on the signal but i have hit a dead end. However here is what i have tried.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Project.teams.through)
def update_team_information(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action in ["post_add", "post_remove", "post_clear"]:
        for team_id in instance.teams.all().values_list('id', flat=True):
            team = Team.objects.get(pk=team_id)
            team.update_information()
```

Comment: Please *don't* use signals... django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: You are using ManyToMany in a wrong way, you don't need to write it in both Project and Team. Just use in one of the model, you can get its relation from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need at all for signals. You are using the [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) the wrong way. Such relation is, like any relation in Django, bi-directional.

So you don't need to specify it in both ways, if you specify one in `Project` for example to `Team`s, you can access for a `Team` the `Project`s. Indeed:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # …
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', blank=True, related_name='projects')


# …


class Team(models.Model):
    # …
    # no projects
    pass
```

This thus means that if you add a `Team` to a `Project`, with:

```
my_project.teams.add(my_team)
```

then `my_team` will automatically have `my_project` as project:

```
my_team.projects.all()  # contains my_project
```